# Place to share cool CSS3 tricks

Tags: animation, html, css, slider, keyframe

I just wrote a pure CSS3 DIV slider, It uses `@keyframe` and other CSS tricks to slide divs. On the hover, the slide pauses. You can embed youtube videos, link images, embed text etc.
It isn't ver user friendly but I will probably work on that. Where can I share it?

http://jsfiddle.net/sQb7U/1/

Have a look at the CSS in there, any ways to improve it? The whole trick is not use any JavaScript. I know there is no fallback for non-CSS3 browsers but I don't really mind. Any suggestions.

Comment: Why the downvote on this? It is a perfectly valid question!

Comment: I think I will be using this. Fantastic.

Comment: If the question is "Where can I share it?", it's more appropriate for [meta] if anywhere. If the question is "How can I improve it?", please be much more specific about your problem - or the question is just open-ended.

Comment: @Madmartigan How can I improve the CSS? And where do I share it when it's complete?

Comment: @nmagerko This one is much easier to use: http://jsfiddle.net/sQb7U/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I share it?

Right here! The [suggested way](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) of providing useful answers to common problems is to ask a question describing the problem you've solved, and answer it yourself. This provides an opportunity for others who have encountered a similar problem to comment and provide alternative solutions while still leaving the information available for anyone that is looking for an answer to the question to find it here on SO.

Comment: @user1090389 - Exactly. Just make sure you use the appropriate QA format for the information you post. (Ask the question describing what your solution resolves, and then post your answer as the response.)